# Date conversion in grails inside javascript

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I am creating one date field in my gsp by below code by using native grails date format:

```
<tr><td><label>Delivery date: </label>
<g:datePicker name="myDate" date="${new Date()}" id="delDate" /></td></tr>
```

While catching the date by id in javascript, it is showing null. My code is as follows:

```
var delDate=$('#delDate').val();

alert("date"+ deldate) is showing dateundefined.
```

How can I get the date in string format so that further I can pass it to json as value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work, since the `g:datePicker` tag translates into 5 HTML `<select>` (day, month, year,hour,minute).

My suggestion:

- remove the `id="delDate"` attribute,
- reconstruct the date this way:

```js
var d = new Date($('#myDate_year').val(),$('#myDate_month').val(),$('#myDate_day').val(),$('#myDate_hour').val(),$('#myDate_minute').val(),$('#myDate_minute').val());

alert(d.toJSON());
```

If you want to use specific date formatters I strongly suggest using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Hi Phil, Can I convert the date Wed Oct 15 11:35:22 UTC+0530 2014
 to only 20141015 format,because I have to pass that date in string format only,like 20141015. Does date.toJSON() convert the date to pure string format.

Comment: after converting the date as var delDate = new Date($('#myDate_year').val(),$('#myDate_month').val(),$('#myDate_day').val(),$('#myDate_hour').val(),$('#myDate_minute').val(),$('#myDate_minute').val());..the deldate is one month forward.e.g::if I am selecting 15th May 2010,in javascript it is showing 15th June 2010.

Comment: you could simply do something like this 

`var d =$('#myDate_year').val()+$('#myDate_month').val()+$('#myDate_day').val()`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use **value** instead of **date** attribute in **g:datePicker** tag. You can see the documentation for that [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/datePicker.html).

```
<g:datePicker name="myDate" value="${new Date()}" id="delDate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no `@id` in `datePicker` tag. see [ref-doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/datePicker.html), only `@name`.

so, you JS call should be

```
var delDate=$('#myDate').val();
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.Still it is showing dateundefined in alert.

Comment: see the generated html code: there's no single field with the the date formatted. Instead there are at least 3 drop-downs with a hidden field. Looks like you have to concatenate the date value yourself

Comment: Hi, Thats not teh html code. alert("date"+ deldate) has been given by me,so that when I submit the page it should pop up showing date 14-Oct-2014.But it is showing dateundefined.That means no value is coming from date field in g:script by name label.It is coming null.